# Array Combine Question in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

HI,

I got two array.

```
var_dump($tbDateArr);
var_dump($tbTitleArr);
```

output:

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'eventDate' => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'eventDate' => string '16' (length=2)
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'eventTitle' => string 'mar' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'eventTitle' => string 'tri' (length=10)
```

BTW,I print them as this,

```
print_r($tbDateArr);
echo '<br>';
print_r($tbTitleArr);
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [eventDate] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [eventDate] => 16 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [eventTitle] => mar ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [eventTitle] => tri ) )
```

I tried to combin them,

```
$dataArr = array_combine($tbDateArr, $tbTitleArr);
```

I JUST WANT THE SIMPLY RESULT as this,

```
Array
(
    [5]  => mar
    [16]    => tri

)
```

Is there anything wrong? Appreciated for your help.

**[updated with array_merge]**

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'eventDate' => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'eventDate' => string '16' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
      public 'eventTitle' => string 'fuzhou mar' (length=10)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'eventTitle' => string 'weihai tri' (length=10)
```

Comment: i am unable to understand what is your desirable result. is it the 2 or 4 key pair value you expect?

Comment: I only expect 2 key pair value. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `$tbDateArr` and `$tbTitleArr` entries only have a single property (`eventDate` and `eventTitle` respectively), you can do this:

```
$array = array_combine(
    array_map('current', $tbDateArr),
    array_map('current', $tbTitleArr)
);
```

If they have (or can have) more than a single property, you're better off using a good old `foreach`, assuming they have matching keys (if they don't, just `array_values` them beforehand):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($tbDateArr as $key => $value) {
    $array[$value] = $tbTableArr[$key];
}
```

Comment: YES! Works quite well. I never use `array_map` before. looks a deeper statement.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
this works

```
$arr1  = array(
    "5",
    "16",
);

$arr2  = array(
    "mar",
    "tri",
);

$result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi, No. I if I use array_merge, It will generated 4 objects in new array. Updated in my post.

Comment: what is the desired result then

Comment: Simply two obj in new array.Array`( [5]  => mar   [16]    => tri)`

Comment: could you print_r Your two arrays rather then dump them please

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly combine the arrays, since the values you need are stored as properties in objects -- you have to pull these values out and use them:

```
$keys   = array_map('getEventDate', $tbDateArr);
$values = array_map('getEventDate', $tbTitleArr);

print_r(array_combine($keys, $values));

function getEventDate($o) {
    return $o->eventDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine arrays which containing objects. array_combine using its first argument for keys second argument as values.